# Executable file created by launch4j is not working

Tags: java, eclipse

I have created a java Applet program using eclipse. It is successfully producing outputs when i run it through eclipse. Then I have converted it into jar and using launch4j i have converted .jar file into .exe file . I have followed the ways suggested in SO to do it. launch4j successfully created the .exe file .I have done the following things in launch4j

- Specified Output file with .exe extension
- specified jar file
- specified min jre version
- saved and clicked build on button

when i double click on it , it's not working.Have i missed anything? I don't know why . Anyone please help me.

Comment: Does the executable jar work before you use create the exe?

Comment: If jar file is getting executed successfully , then I guess you do not need exe again since I guess your goal is to make the file executable with single click...

Comment: From experience that I have from using Launch4j , There are several copmlexities and disadvantages using launch4j. I honestly suggest you to stick to jar files if your only goal is to make the application work with single click.

Comment: Yes Stunner , My aim is same as opening a calc application with single click and getting inputs , producing outputs. My jar file is successfully opening and contains class and other files too.What shall i do now to make it an application like calc? please any suggestion.

Comment: I have created jar only not Runnable jar. Done it by right clicking on the project and selected export -> java -> jar file . Not Runnable jar.

Comment: Thanks Stunner . I have solved the problem . I have converted applet to JApplet and add a main method from which i started the JApplet. Then converted it into Runnable Jar . It works perfectly now.